# Computing simple moving average using Map Reduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I stumbled upon this article:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/04/simple-moving-average-secondary-sort-and-mapreduce-part-3/

which mentions how to calculate moving average using Hadoop.

Please notice that all the records for a KEY should be sorted and then reduced. Now assume that the records for a particular KEY are spread across all the shards of Mongo cluster. In such case, would it be possible to calculate the moving average?

I understand that Mongo does the map reduce at each node. The prime requirement to solve this problem is to make sure all the emits for a map be reduced in a single reduce phase. If that's the case, then Mongo Map Reduce will never be able to solve such problems. Is there some basic misunderstanding?

Also, with billions of rows, and petabytes of data, why is it that Hadoop Reduce phase doesn't crash out of memory, since it has to deal with at least several TBs of mapped data.

Comment: This is somewhere where hadoop will rule better, you would need to two MRs with MongoDB to do this. Also about the part that isn't marked as a question, it is because MongoDB stores parts in memory and then each step gets written to a temp table, so if a step does exceed the max allowed RAM then it will crash out.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how it can be done in MongoDB? If each node is going to reduce the mapped data on that node, already the statistical information is lost.. right? It would be awesome if you could explain with code.

Comment: No, since each node will hold a range so in theory when the data comes back it should be able to have a moving average for the range possesed on that shard, it is merely a case of sorting the returned results from all nodes to make a sorted moving average. It should be possible, of course you would have to get the results of the first MR and feed it to a second sorted to fix any errors from not having the true value of the last datum, it is not totally clear in my head but I am sure if I was given like a week I could maybe come up with something, but before that I would give up and use hadoop

Comment: Can you explain why Hadoop doesn't crash out of memory for such computation? From my understanding, all the reduce will happen on one node, where all the records for a KEY will be reduced. This should result in huge memory overhead on that node, since TBs of data needs to be present there.. How does Hadoop handle such huge amount of data?

Comment: I believe that, unlike MongoDB, hadoop, just like SQL when processing a large join, will write out things to disk and read only when needed with the OS using swap as a temporary memory holder for certain things probably. MongoDB does more in RAM before writing to disk as such it will easily bail out

Comment: But if the mapped data itself becomes bigger than what that node could hold, wouldn't Hadoop also crash in such a case?

Comment: Tbh I do not know the particulars but yes, if no data can fit on logic would tell me that it would crash

Comment: Okay. One more thing, does a merge sort kind of phase also happens in MongoDB Map Reduce?

Comment: You mean a reduce?, that will merge "keys"

Comment: Yes so MongoDB will output emit document like: `{key: key_vlaue, [{doc_field:doc_value},{next_doc_key:next_doc_value}]}` and in the reduce it will chop up the key document into batches of 101 results and run the reduce for each batch merging recursively until the entire key is reduced to one document

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30105/discussion-between-p-prasad-and-sammaye)

Comment: Have you resolved this using mongodb's map reduce?